# What is $\lnot a\to b$ in clausal form?

Tags: logic

I understand that $ a \to b$ is $ \lnot a \lor b $.
So is $ \lnot a\to b$ clausal form $ a \lor b$ ?

Comment: A priori it would be $(\neg\neg a)\vee b$

Comment: Depends whether you mean $(\neg a)\rightarrow b$ or $\neg (a\rightarrow b)$.